# Colouring in a large number of individual sections of a plot. How can I do this?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an array with 250,000 entries.  I want to plot this as a histogram so that I can ultimately colour different individual elements in different colours depending on their location (I have a list to compare to so that I know which colour goes where).  However, the array is not in a "standard" form.

Each index corresponds to the position I want it in the graph.  I want `myarray[0]` to be at the start of the x axis, `myarray[1]` to be next, and so on, with the values of `myarray` going up the y axis.

Simply using `plot(myarray)` is fine in itself to give one an idea of the shape of the graph, but now that I want to colour elements in individually, a line plot doesn't seem to be an option.  I tried using bar chart but for whatever reason my computer struggles to compute/render such a huge bar chart.

Is there any way to go about doing this in a reasonable manner, or am I doomed to having my PC bricked every time I try and plot this bar chart?

The end goal is colouring different sections different colours.  I assumed the best way to do this would be with the bar chart, but alternatively is it possible to use plot(myarray) and then shade different areas under the graph using my list I intend to compare to?  Each element of the array has a different colour that changes rapidly.  I can't simply colour in the first 33% one colour, the second 33% another colour and then the final 34% in another colour.  It's very "random" in appearance (although predetermined) where I want these colours to go.

Below is how I tried to plot my 250k bar bar chart, where `eloss` is my 250,000 elements long array:

```
bins=_np.linspace(0,len(eloss), len(eloss)) 
_plt.bar(bins, eloss, width=0.1, color='blue')
```

This freezes three of my computers very quickly.  Any help would be much appreciated, the solution seems obvious (plot three bar charts each with different colours and then overlay them), but having used 3 different computers, each of increasing specs, none can handle it.  As long as I can colour in the segments, I don't care whether it's a histogram/bar chart/line graph.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completly sure to understand your problem, but if I do, there could be a solution:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Fake data that should mimic yours
x = np.random.random(250000)
y = np.array(range(250000))

#create a list of color for each point
list_to_divide = range(10) # The list by wish you want your data divided
list_color = [plt.get_cmap('CMRmap')(i) for i in np.linspace(0, 0.9, len(list_to_divide))]
dict_color = dict(zip(list_to_divide, list_color))
c = map(int, x*10) #assign each of your point to a distinct category, here I divise my data by rank from 0 to 10
color = []
for i in c:
    color.append(list_color[i])
#color is now a list of the same dimension that your data and will be use to assign the color for each point

#Draw your plot
plt.scatter(x,y, s = 2, color = color, edgecolors = 'none')
```

On my laptop, it work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Drawing a large number of bars is a very inefficient way to do this in matplotlib.

Your initial approach could be more easily accomplished by using `fill_between`, which will also draw *much* faster.

As a quick example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(1982)

# Generate some interesting random data to plot...
num = 250000
data = np.random.normal(0, 1, num).cumsum()
data -= data.min()
x = np.arange(data.size)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
path = ax.fill_between(x, data, facecolor='cadetblue', linewidth=0.1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you'd like to color these, it's easiest to plot an image and then clip it by the extent of the data.  Once again, this is *much* faster to draw than 250k independent bars:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch
np.random.seed(1982)

# Generate some interesting random data to plot...
num = 250000
data = np.random.normal(0, 1, num).cumsum()
data -= data.min()
x = np.arange(data.size)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(data[None,:], extent=[x.min(), x.max(), data.min(), data.max()],
               aspect='auto', cmap='gnuplot')

xy = np.column_stack([x, data])
xy = np.vstack([[0, 0], xy, [x[-1], 0], [0, 0]])
path = ax.add_patch(PathPatch(Path(xy), facecolor='none', linewidth=0.1))
im.set_clip_path(path)

plt.show()
```

[image]